# RAM Listed in dmidecode and bios but not used?

Tags: boot, 20.04, ram

I am running ubuntu 20.04 on a b450m ds3h motherboard. I have 4 8GB ram stick which individually tested all work on the same board. However when I place all of them in the bios sees and lists them, ubuntus dmidecode sees and lists them however ubuntu only uses 16gb. I do have a graphics card that is detected and used. I have also run all available updates just in case. Any ideas? It almost seems like I just need to be able to tell ubuntu to boot and use it somehow. At any rate you have my thanks for taking your time.

dmidecode -t 6 output:

```
# dmidecode 3.2
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 3.2.1 present.
# SMBIOS implementations newer than version 3.2.0 are not
# fully supported by this version of dmidecode.
```

dmidecode -t 0 | grep -i version

```
Version: F3
```

Updated bios to version F51

lshw -C memory output:

```
*-firmware                
   description: BIOS
   vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
   physical id: 0
   version: F51
   date: 07/29/2020
   size: 64KiB
   capacity: 16MiB
   capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
*-memory
   description: System Memory
   physical id: 9
   slot: System board or motherboard
   size: 32GiB
 *-bank:0
      description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 1866 MHz (0.5 ns)
      product: CMK16GX4M2B3000C15
      vendor: Unknown
      physical id: 0
      serial: 00000000
      slot: DIMM 0
      size: 8GiB
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 1866MHz (0.5ns)
 *-bank:1
      description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 1866 MHz (0.5 ns)
      product: CMK16GX4M2B3000C15
      vendor: Unknown
      physical id: 1
      serial: 00000000
      slot: DIMM 1
      size: 8GiB
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 1866MHz (0.5ns)
 *-bank:2
      description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 1866 MHz (0.5 ns)
      product: F4-3200C16-8GVGB
      vendor: Unknown
      physical id: 2
      serial: 00000000
      slot: DIMM 0
      size: 8GiB
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 1866MHz (0.5ns)
 *-bank:3
      description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 1866 MHz (0.5 ns)
      product: F4-3200C16-8GVGB
      vendor: Unknown
      physical id: 3
      serial: 00000000
      slot: DIMM 1
      size: 8GiB
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 1866MHz (0.5ns)
*-cache:0
   description: L1 cache
   physical id: b
   slot: L1 - Cache
   size: 768KiB
   capacity: 768KiB
   clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
   capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
   configuration: level=1
*-cache:1
   description: L2 cache
   physical id: c
   slot: L2 - Cache
   size: 4MiB
   capacity: 4MiB
   clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
   capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
   configuration: level=2
*-cache:2
   description: L3 cache
   physical id: d
   slot: L3 - Cache
   size: 16MiB
   capacity: 16MiB
   clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
   capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
   configuration: level=3
```

Memtest report:

```
System Information
EFI Specifications  2.70
System  
Manufacturer    Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
Product Name    B450M DS3H
Version     Default string
Serial Number   Default string
BIOS    
Vendor  American Megatrends Inc.
Version     F51
Release Date    07/29/2020
Baseboard   
Manufacturer    Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
Product Name    B450M DS3H-CF
Version     x.x
Serial Number   Default string
CPU Type    AMD Ryzen 7 2700X Eight-Core
CPU Clock   3731 MHz [Turbo: 3730.7 MHz]
# Logical Processors    16
L1 Cache    16 x 96K (82532 MB/s)
L2 Cache    16 x 512K (64487 MB/s)
L3 Cache    1 x 16384K (20557 MB/s)
Memory  16347M (8553 MB/s)
DIMM Slot #0    8GB DDR4 XMP PC4-23900
    Corsair / CMK16GX4M2B3000C15
    15-17-17-35 / 2998 MHz / 1.350V
DIMM Slot #1    8GB DDR4 XMP PC4-25600
    G Skill Intl / F4-3200C16-8GVGB
    16-18-18-38 / 3200 MHz / 1.350V
DIMM Slot #2    8GB DDR4 XMP PC4-23900
    Corsair / CMK16GX4M2B3000C15
    15-17-17-35 / 2998 MHz / 1.350V
DIMM Slot #3    8GB DDR4 XMP PC4-25600
    G Skill Intl / F4-3200C16-8GVGB
    16-18-18-38 / 3200 MHz / 1.350V
Result summary
Test Start Time 2020-10-27 01:24:38
Elapsed Time    5:48:06
Memory Range Tested     0x0 - 41F380000 (16883MB)
CPU Selection Mode  Parallel (All CPUs)
ECC Polling     Enabled
# Tests Passed  48/48 (100%)
Test    # Tests Passed  Errors
Test 0 [Address test, walking ones, 1 CPU]  4/4 (100%)  0
Test 1 [Address test, own address, 1 CPU]   4/4 (100%)  0
Test 2 [Address test, own address]  4/4 (100%)  0
Test 3 [Moving inversions, ones & zeroes]   4/4 (100%)  0
Test 4 [Moving inversions, 8-bit pattern]   4/4 (100%)  0
Test 5 [Moving inversions, random pattern]  4/4 (100%)  0
Test 6 [Block move, 64-byte blocks]     4/4 (100%)  0
Test 7 [Moving inversions, 32-bit pattern]  4/4 (100%)  0
Test 8 [Random number sequence]     4/4 (100%)  0
Test 9 [Modulo 20, ones & zeros]    4/4 (100%)  0
Test 10 [Bit fade test, 2 patterns, 1 CPU]  4/4 (100%)  0
Test 13 [Hammer test]   4/4 (100%)  0
```

Comment: Addendum: I have reseated the ram, cpu(checked for bent pins), and graphics card because i needed to get at the cmos to drain the power just in case.

Comment: What is the output of `sudo dmidecode -t 6`?   Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1286934/edit) your question and add the output.  Also, is the BIOS set to Ganged or Unganged mode for the RAM?  I don't think the latter part would make a difference for how much RAM is seen, but I have found that Unganged mode works better.

Comment: Let's see if `dmidecode` can get your BIOS version.  Try running `sudo dmidecode -t 0 | grep -i version`  The newest BIOS for your board should be `F51`

Comment: *looks at bios instructions* woof I've got a ways to go. brb.

Comment: bios updated now. I'm looking through for any new options

Comment: What model Ryzen? Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C memory`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema updated with lshw output.

Comment: @SimpleRynocerous Yes, two DIMMs look like Crucial memory, and two DIMMs are a who-knows-what brand. That may be the problem. `Memtest` should tell us. Have you overclocked CPU or RAM?

Comment: @heynnema to my knowledge i have not overclocked the cpu. I did this morning change the bios ram speed from auto at like 2100 something to the 1800 something that was reported by dmidecode. I have also updated my answer with the report from memtest. It too sees the ram but only tested 16Gbs of it. I have another computer with some other ram I could take out and try in this one. Its odd to me though.. this ram in this configuration has worked in the past but after being off for some time it seems to have stopped of its own accord.

Comment: @SimpleRynocerous The `memtest` shows that the specs for the DIMMs are different, and the "SPD Latency" (Google it) and access modes appear to be different, and the speeds are different, effecting how the computer sizes the memory. I'll bet that the Corsair memory was on the memory list, and the G.Skill was not, correct? You may need to return the G.Skill memory, and get matching Corsair memory to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gigabyte B450M DS3H (rev. 1.0)

[Specs](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/B450M-DS3H-rev-10/sp#sp)

**BIOS**

Your BIOS is current at F51.

**Ryzen**

AMD Ryzen 7 2700X Eight-Core

Ryzen processors are notorious for memory compatibility issues. When individual DIMMs work, but fully populated memory doesn't work, then the memory may not be compatible.

Go to this [CPU Support List](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/B450M-DS3H-rev-10/support#support-cpu) and determine the model/series of your Ryzen CPU.

Then go to this [Memory Support List](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/B450M-DS3H-rev-10/support#support-doc) and locate the list that's for your Ryzen CPU model/series.

Confirm that your installed memory is on the list. It's probably not. You might be looking at replacing your current memory.

**memtest**

Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

**Update #1:**

The `memtest` output shows that the specs for the DIMMs are different, and the "SPD Latency" (Google it) and access modes appear to be different, and the speeds are different, effecting how the computer sizes the memory. I'll bet that the Corsair memory was on the memory list, and the G.Skill was not, correct? You may need to return the G.Skill memory, and get matching Corsair memory to fix this.

Comment: Two sticks are newer versions than the same model on the list and two are on the list. I tested again this morning and the mother board does pick up all of the ram as well as mix matched in whichever slots i choose. I have to go to work but after I'll run the memtest. Thank you for the suggestions my good man.

Comment: I have found my answer, not a solution but an answer and your response got me there. The ryzen 7 I have does not seem to support the G. Skill ram. However the ryzen 3 I have sitting around does. In any case I thank you.

Comment: if you were curious on my next moves. I am ordering an additional 16gb of the kind explicitly on the support list for the ryzen 7 and giving the 16gb not on the list to the SO so its a win win sorta. This built is a couple years old and why or how the GSkill ram ever worked with the ryzen 7 is a mystery to me.

Comment: @SimpleRynocerous Thanks for the update! Make sure that the 16G RAM that you order exactly matches the remaining (Corsair?) RAM that you keep,

Comment: Well.. I ordered the same model of corsair ram and installed it and switched back from the ryzen 5 to the 7 and it still only detects half of the ram once booted to OS. vOv If I ever figure it out I will let you know but for the moment the ryzen 5 will do.

Comment: @SimpleRynocerous Did you run `memtest`? Show me the latest `sudo lshw -C memory`.

Comment: If `memtest` runs OK, then I'd suspect a bad Ryzen 7.